# Which is the order of words in Doppelkonjunktionen nicht..., sondern?

Tags: grammar, standard-german

**Doppelkonjunktionen** nicht..., sondern...

Wie ist die korrekte Wortstellung?

> Nicht + Hauptsatz, sondern + Hauptsatz

oder

> Nicht + Inversion, sondern + Inversion

oder

> Nicht + Inversion, sondern + Hauptsatz

oder gar:

> Nicht + Hauptsatz, sondern + Inversion

Welcher dieser Sätze ist dann richtig?

> 1. Nicht die Freunde kosten zu viel Zeit, sondern die Arbeit dauert zu lange.
> 2. Nicht kosten die Freunde zu viel Zeit, sondern  dauert die Arbeit zu lange

Comment: Vielleicht: Nicht die Freunde kosten zu viel Zeit, sondern die Arbeit dauert zu lange.

Comment: Oder: Nicht kosten die Freunde zu viel Zeit, sondern  dauert die Arbeit zu lange

Comment: Joe are you content with my additional edits? (btw, you can also ask in English here) I hope it wasn't against your problem, but if that was the case feel free to eoll back to a previous revision ;)

Comment: @Vogel612... there is no such thing as "inversion" in German. Any way to avoid that word?

Comment: Inversion is when you write verb and subject instead of subject an verb

Comment: @Emanuel [duden objects](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Inversion)

Comment: @Vogel612... well, what about "Gestern wurde zum ersten mal seit 200 Jahren wieder ein Yeti gesehen." oder "Oh, davon hat mir gestern auch mein Chef erzählt."... the term inversion makes students think that the subject either comes right in front or right after the verb and that is just misses the core principles of German which is why I object so harshly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Verb** ist immer Position 2.
**Hauptsatz** ist Subject(pos. 1) + Verb(pos.2)

> Nicht (pos. 0) + Hauptsatz, sondern (pos. 0) + Hauptsatz

z.B: Nicht die Freunde kosten zu viel Zeit, sondern die Arbeit dauert zu lange.

Aber es is gut auch

Die Freunde kosten zu viel Zeit nicht, sondern die Arbeit dauert zu lange.

Comment: Der zweite Satz könnte mit etwas anderem als Beispiel funktionieren, aber so klingt er für mich einfach nur falsch.

Comment: Die Wortstellung des zweiten Satzes ist falsch ('nicht', 'kosten' vertauschen). 'Die Freunde kosten nicht zu viel Zeit, sondern die Arbeit dauert zu lange' ist grammatikalisch völlig akzeptabel; thematisch würde ich erwarten, daß vorher die Freunde das primäre Thema war, während im ersten Satz die Zeit diese Rolle einnahm. Der Unterschied ist jedoch sehr subtil und spielt im Alltag keine Rolle.